# Fonts are not clear in the pdf

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, cs6

Currently i'm working on my resume using Photoshop cs6. When i get the pdf version of my CV,i can see some of the fonts are in grey color and some of were not there.I'll appreciate if someone help me to resolve this

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why are you using Photoshop to create a resumé?. Why not just use a word processor?

Comment: actually it gives a perfect look

Comment: If it looks perfect, then why have you posted this question?  Use a word processor for typed documents, not Photoshop.  It's the wrong application. I can use a hammer to fix a screw, but a screwdriver would be better. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: The issues you are citing is sort of *why* using a raster *image* editor for a resume is a bad idea. A great deal is determined by mere *construction* of the file in the raster image editor and any output settings/requirements. [**See Here.**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/39548/3270) You *may* be getting grey and missing type due to layering or blending within the file. Missing type may be due to licensing restrictions for a font. It's difficult to state.

Comment: @BillyKerr you are so rude to me.i said Photoshop gives a perfect look than word processor,that's why i used it. When i's saving as a pdf i got this error,that's why i post the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried printing it to see if the anomalies print?  They often just have to do with screen rendering (if you're using vector).  As mentioned above, I don't recommend using photoshop for this.  Go with InDesign, even Illustrator or a WordProcessor.  Photoshop is mostly a raster program.